# Captcha doesn't work with IE

Tags: bug, status-declined, captcha

All I can see is "I am human being".

I don't know which version my IE is, I don't know where to check it, but it came with Windows 7, so it can't be that old.

Comment: *Dude*, you've been a a member for all of four months. Why do you think you're qualified to make these kinds of statements?

Comment: Ahh.. If quality standards are the main reason these sites are going to die, now I understand why Yahoo Answers is so great!

Comment: @daniel, i have had multiple accounts because i wasnt able to register for some reason, and thus unable to report because there is no other way to connect than registering account here, those accounts die when my browser cookies die, thats why multiple accounts.

Comment: @slhck, my problem with quality standards has nothing to do with ANSWERS, but if you are inable to post a QUESTION because you wrote "dude" there, then is that really helping anyone?

Comment: See it from another point of view: Who's the "dude" you're addressing? Does it add any valuable info? No, therefore, please leave it out. Questions need some love too. See this blog post for the background: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/

Comment: @slhck, are you saying you cant understand what i would be refering to if i write "my dude" instead of "my player" ? (or even more validly written "my character" eww) see it from another perspective: what if my game is about a player who is supposedly called Dude for the entire storyline ? thats the problem with this whole word banning: it cant understand the meanings at all, it just blindly searches for specific words. i have never liked word banning for that exact same reason, it just doesnt work, and it never will. but you guys made it even worse: you dont even give a hint what is wrong.

Comment: wow, -5 now, because im using IE you can vote down my bug report? very constructive from your side.

Comment: Yes, in fact, [I don't like word banning either](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108815/159624). I think it's the wrong way to tackle low quality posts. However, I think the low quality filter does a pretty decent job, and I don't think it would block you from posting the word "Dude" in a question if it weren't for other issues (this even includes writing proper English in the sense of capitalizing `i`s).

Comment: **This is not a bug report**. This is a rant that opens with some kind of a bug report. A proper bug report would at least include the version of Internet Explorer you're using and a better description of the actual bug.

Comment: @slhck, My original post was a bug report, the rest talk about it has nothing to do with the original post. but you guys want to think that way because i am "infidel" who uses IE, so its easy to get mad about it and blame the "ranting" to feel justified about it, i see this pattern everywhere, nothing new to me. I dont think its needed to say version number if im not able to get it. i was expecting people to tell how to get it, but no. that didnt happen, you just want to strike me down for my ideologies, which are wrong, of course.

Comment: I don't care if you use IE or Netscape or Lynx. I don't even think *anybody* does really care here, and there are a lot of IE users out there. Even on Super User. I removed the offending part from your question. I can't reproduce your bug because I don't own a PC though. Maybe you're expecting a bit too much, but you definitely fail to see how that rant of yours lead to the downvotes and the discussion.

Comment: i wouldnt have written the "rant" at all if the quality control didnt prevent me from posting my bug report because it was too short.

Comment: In fact alot of people use IE http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer

Comment: AND your bug report WAS too short. You basically said, "it doesn't work and I'm not putting ANY effort into trying fix it. I want you guys to fix it without access to my computer and without knowing any other info. If you can't I'm going to get mad and through a temper tantrum"... If you don't know how to google how to find your IE version or at least download another browser to test with then I am simply speechless...

Comment: @kyle, heh, i was kind enough to let you know about this bug. i even took the time to register through this annoying process; first i didnt get my activation email, and shit like that, wow im whining again, what a pompous idiot i am, because your site is buggy, i am pompous! most people wont even report bugs, they just silently suffer. if you cant appreciate that the users reports bugs then... im simply speechless. its hard enough to register here and get through these anti-spam / qualification processes, which stops most people from reporting anything.

Comment: Your still bitching at the wrong person, I'm not a developer for stack exchange and this isn't my site. I don't care if you report anything or ever come to this site gain, I was just giving you the reason I downvoted...

Answer (score 5):

With regards to the Captcha, have you tried clearing your cache?

With regards to the rest of you question, you hit the nail on the head. The community did get upset with the amount of low quality, bad questions that have been asked, and the Question Standard is the **bare minimum that is required** to be able to post a question and answer the community will accept.

If you can't meet that standard, there is an extremely good chance your question will be closed and down voted, so I would suggest you at least try and meet that standard.

However, your also under no obligation to use any of the SE sites. Keep in mind, it is a free service, and SE can set any standards they may feel will improve the quality on the site.

**Further Info**

No one except the developers know what the standards criteria are, so we cannot provide any information as to how you can fix it. The How To Ask a question page it refers to does however make it easier to get it right.

Comment: how has cache anything to do with this? and what cache youre talking about? and how does this make it possible for me to keep my writings? if i refresh the page, i will lose everything. i have never noticed much of low quality posts here, sometimes few, but didnt really bother me, thats why there is downvote button... which i find funny i got -2 already! this site definitely doesnt want to hear any critics. i dont care how much you own a site, if its something like social site (like this is), theres no point trying to force everyone into _your_ standards. that will only harm the community.

Comment: not to mention nobody knows these standards, theres no way of knowing how to write, you can just keep trying and guess whats wrong, for example i once wrote "dude" and i couldnt post the whole question because of ONE single word thats considered bad. but i thought it would fit there since it was about a game... that took long time to figure out what was wrong with my writing.

Comment: @winuser If you don' even know what browser cache is, I am not entirely convinced you should be asking questions on Super User. Also, gaming is off topic for this site. It also explains why the system is rejecting your questions. We don't have anything against critics, we do however have issues with people that posts rants about how unfair we are, instead of posting objective arguments as to why they are having issues.

Comment: @winuser a couple other things: a) it's not a social networking site. It's a question and answer site. b) you say you haven't noticed many low-quality questions - that is specifically _because_ the moderators work very hard to remove and edit low-quality content. If we didn't do this, then the signal to noise ratio would be much lower.

Comment: @winuser If the automatic post quality scoring system would tell you exactly what's wrong, you'd just be gaming it by fixing the few things that are *indicators* of bad post quality without improving the actual post quality (e.g. *dude* might indicate slang or colloquialism not suitable for a worldwide audience).

Comment: @Diago, Wait... to ask questions here you must be pro in everything? isnt the point of asking to learn? lol. i wasnt talking about this site, i was talking about stack-exchange network which consists of many sites. (at)nhinkle: i didnt mean this is facebook, but as any forum-kind places; people dont share one opinion or view of things, thus its pointless to force people to think alike you do. at least put up a list of words that are banned. or highlight them too.

Comment: @winuser Actually, our FAQ does indeed say that. **Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users**. We expect our users at least to know what browser cache is and how to check the version of the OS, and IE, they are running. If you can't do the basics, you are indeed in the wrong place.

Comment: @Diago, where is the site for retards like me who can admit they arent perfect and all-knowing Gods, then? i was able to get IE version before, but this new windows 7 has hidden the feature, as i said earlier: many times: new windows versions remove features. thats not my fault.

Comment: @winuser Actually. The feature wasn't removed. It still in precisely the same place it has been since V1. Help -> About Internet Explorer. As for the rest of your question, I really don't know, since SU doesn't have any perfect or all-knowing Gods on it.

Comment: @diago, i dont have "help" button anywhere... maybe i have removed it if it was in some useless toolbar?

Comment: @winuser Unfortunately technical support is not my field so I am not entirely sure where to start to help with that. Since I can't see your screen, I wouldn't even know where to start and advise you. Maybe give MS support a call, or otherwise chat to a local techie and see if they can assist.

Comment: @diago, the original reason why i didnt even bother to tell the version is because i already told you that im using IE which came with Windows7 and that should probably be enough information for any web-developer. im sure they know these things without the need for specific version numbers, and even if they did need they wouldnt be fixing it just for specific version number.

Comment: @winuser IE8 ships with windows 7... But there is also IE9. Are we suppose to guess as to the state of your automatic updates? I just repaired a win7 pc that still has IE 8 so it's entirely possible.

Comment: @kyle, its only 2 versions, not a big deal to test with both. and if you already used one and saw no bugs, then you can know for 100% sure that i have the other version. there shouldnt even be any kind of testing, the first mistake on that code was to use something like javascript which is known to be the most incompatible creation of mankind. why dont we make the emergency exit door work with electric lock that requires 10 number code? because there simply isnt NEED FOR IT. a simple freaking handle does the job. tech guys go google for img tag and input tag, its all you need for this to work.

Comment: @winuser We aren't devs we are just regular users, like you. If you want our help you may have to check your browser version for us, if you can't do that then you won't get help. Simple as that. If you want help from stack exchange feel free to send them an email.